Can we always prove whether a statement is undecidable by adding consistency strength?
So, if a statement is independent of a list of axioms then the system cannot prove it. For example, CH is independent from ZFC. But if we accept ZFC is consistent then we can prove CH must be independent of it. Of course because of Gödel's incompleteness theorem we can cook up more statements that we can't prove we can't prove, but can those just be remedied by adding as an axiom the consistency of the theories we have, ad infinitum, or does this stop working in principle after a point?
An equivalent thing to ask for, which would be instructive to me, is an example of an undecidable statement of such a type that we cannot determine it is so even if we allow ourselves to add consistency strength.

ZFC + Con(ZFC) + Con(ZFC + Con(ZFC)) + … still cannot prove ZFC + “There exists an inaccessible cardinal” is consistent, if I’m not mistaken. Does that count as an example?

@DavidGao yes, that's an example! It leads me to another question (which I think you know I'm about to look into and maybe ask another question about), but I think I should leave this question the way it is.

@DavidGao wait I thought ZFC+Con(ZFC) proved that the existence of large cardinals was a question independent of ZFC. Because if a large cardinal existed it would prove Con(ZFC), therefore ZFC proves that it can't prove a large cardinal exists without also proving it's own consistency

I’m not sure what you meant. ZFC does prove that the existence of an inaccessible cardinal implies Con(ZFC), yes. That has nothing to do with whether ZFC + Con(ZFC) proves Con(ZFC + “there exists an inaccessible cardinal”) though…?

@DavidGao I thought that the independence of existence of an inaccessible cardinal from ZFC was the same thing as asserting Con(ZFC+"an inaccessible ordinal exists") and Con(ZFC+"an inaccessible ordinal does not exist")

Yes? The second assertion just follows from ZFC itself though, so it’s really just the first assertion that matters. And ZFC + Con(ZFC) does not prove the first assertion.

@DavidGao I thought ZFC proves that if an inaccessible cardinal exists then it proves itself consistent. Therefore so long as ZFC is consistent, there is no proof in ZFC that says large cardinals exist. If ZFC proved that they didn't, it wouldn't even be a question though. So it seems like ZFC says that you can or can't add a large cardinal and preserve consistency, which is I think my argument. It's a little bit fuzzy

You’re confusing yourself (then again, consistency issues are quite confusing to begin with). It is indeed true that, assuming ZFC is consistent, then ZFC does not prove inaccessible cardinals exist. Whether ZFC proves they don’t is hard to say, but it is generally believed ZFC does not prove that. However, this is a belief. You can’t actually prove in ZFC that ZFC does not prove “inaccessible cardinals do not exist”, because that’s the same as proving, in ZFC, Con(ZFC + “inaccessible cardinals exist”), which of course is even stronger than Con(ZFC) and therefore impossible to prove in ZFC.

The point being, while Con(ZFC + “inaccessible cardinals exist”) is widely believed to be true, it is not a consequence of ZFC. What I said is just that it’s not even a consequence of ZFC + Con(ZFC), or even ZFC + Con(ZFC) + Con(ZFC + Con(ZFC)) + …

(Also, a small correction to my earlier comment: when I said Con(ZFC + “inaccessible cardinals do not exist”) “just follows from ZFC itself”, I actually meant it follows from Con(ZFC). Of course ZFC cannot prove Con(ZFC + “inaccessible cardinals do not exist”), but ZFC + Con(ZFC) does prove it.)

Your question is a bit unclear to me since you are not putting any restrictions on what you mean by "consistency strength". For example let's assume you are asking the following:
Question: Let $\phi$ be some statement in the language of $\operatorname{ZFC}$ that is independent of $\operatorname{ZFC}$. Is there some (reasonably expressible) theory $T$ so that $\operatorname{ZFC} + \operatorname{Con}(T)$ proves that $\phi$ is independent of $\operatorname{ZFC}$?
If that's your question then the answer is trivially yes. Simply let $T = \operatorname{ZFC} + \text{"$\phi$ is independent of $\operatorname{ZFC}$"}$. Arguing within $\operatorname{ZFC} + \operatorname{Con}(T)$, if $\phi$ were not independent, there is a specific proof $p$ of either $\phi$ or $\neg \phi$. But any model of $T$ (which exists) would see this proof.
Maybe you are asking something along the following lines:
Question: Let $\phi$ be some statement in the language of $\operatorname{ZFC}$ that is independent of $\operatorname{ZFC}$. If we start with the theory $\operatorname{Con}(\operatorname{ZFC})$ and then iteratively construct stronger theories by adding the consistency of the previous theory, do we at some point prove that $\phi$ is independent of $\operatorname{ZFC}$?
This has been touched somewhat in the comments. As has been pointed out, if you recursively define $T_0 = \operatorname{ZFC}$ and $T_{n+1} = T_n + \operatorname{Con}(T_n)$, then no $T_n$ might be able to prove, say the consistency of an innaccessible cardinal. And in fact this is even still true for $T_{\omega} = \bigcup_n T_n$. What if you go beyond $\omega$? The problem with this is that, while there is still a more or less canonical way to formalize $\operatorname{Con}(T_\omega)$ as a statement in $\operatorname{ZFC}$, this becomes less and less clear climbing up the ordinals. Let me just exemplify something funny:
Theorem. There is a Turing machine $e$ accepting exactly the (codes) for formulas in $T_\omega$ and rejecting all other formulas so that $T_\omega + \text{"the theory given by the formulas accepted by machine $e$ is consistent"}$ proves that $\phi$ is independent of $\operatorname{ZFC}$.
Proof. Suppose $e$ is given as an input the formula $\psi$ with Gödel-code $n$. If $\psi \in T_\omega$, then $e$ immediately accepts. If $\psi$ ends in "$\wedge 0 = 1$", $e$ goes through all proofs in $\operatorname{ZFC}$ of length $\leq n$. If any of these prove $\phi$ or $\neg \phi$, $e$ accepts. In all other cases $e$ rejects.
$e$ accepts exactly the formulas in $T_\omega$ as we know that $\phi$ is independent. On the other hand, form the assumption that the theory accepted by $e$ is consistent we can deduce that $\phi$ is independent, because otherwise there is some proof of $\phi$ or $\neg \phi$ of length $m$. Then we find some formula $\psi$ of the form $\chi \wedge 0 = 1$ with large enough code $n \geq m$ and that formula is outright inconsistent and accepted by $e$. $\square$
For some large enough ordinal $\alpha$ it becomes really not clear anymore how to formalize $T_\alpha$ and there is always some way to do so that will prove the independence of $\phi$ just as we did above with $\alpha = \omega$.
